# Android crashes on start

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

My app was working fine, until it crashed once and can't run again only on android. IOS is working fine.
build doesn't catch any error, but when I start it on android studio I get these error log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2cOl.png)

```
  E/unknown:ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext:            mJSIModulePackage not null
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
Process: com.gamo, PID: 17096
java.lang.AssertionError: No source URL loaded, have you initialised the instance?
    at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:35)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.debug.SourceCodeModule.getTypedExportedConstants(SourceCodeModule.java:39)
    at com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeSourceCodeSpec.getConstants(NativeSourceCodeSpec.java:35)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:129)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17096 SIG: 9
```

I already tried gradlew clean, cache clean, enable hermes = true

Comment: Please upload the error as text and not as image.

Comment: Are you using react-native-screens library?

Comment: yes i use react native screens